# Rails integration test: assert_select not working on a <script> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests that test for the presence (or lack thereof) of the Google Analytics javascript under various conditions (mainly, I don't load it if the logged in user is an admin of the system).

My actual script tag in the page looks like this:

```
<script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

If I test for its presence using `assert_match`, it works:

```
assert_match 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', response.body
```

However, if I write the test with an `assert_select` instead, it fails:

```
assert_select "script[src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js']"
```

The error message is:

```
Failure:
AnalyticsTest#test_analytics_load_for_correct_users [/Users/km/Documents/Code/recommender/test/integration/analytics_test.rb:17]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "script[src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js']", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my `assert_select` syntax, any ideas?

Comment: you didn't put your script tag in your question. :)

Comment: it's there:

<script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>